# In Pair.of() : Can you change the name of(S first, T second)?

Tags: java, key-value

```
{
            "first": "1.0",
            "second": "Not Predicted"
        },
        {
            "first": "1.1",
            "second": "Not Predicted"
        }
```

The representation of Pair.of is : Pair<S, T> of(**S first,T second**)
So here is it possible to change the default names **first** and **second** to something we wish to keep ?

Comment: I don't get it. If you want to change names of method arguments, you're more than welcome to in your own code. You're most likely not going to be able to change them in someone else's code. And what's with the JSON snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for Jackson:

Declare serializer for specific class Pair

```java
public static class PairSerializer extends StdSerializer<Pair> {

    public PairSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public PairSerializer(Class<Pair> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Pair value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeObjectField("a", value.getFirst());   // "a" is replacement for "first"
        jgen.writeObjectField("b", value.getSecond());  // "b" is replacement for "second"
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

then you register this serializer and serialize your Pair(s) into JSON

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Pair.class, new PairSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

List<Pair<String, String>> pairs = Arrays.asList(Pair.of("1.0", "Unpredicted"), Pair.of("1.1", "Unpredicted"));

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(pairs));
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "a": "1.0",
    "b": "Unpredicted"
  },
  {
    "a": "1.1",
    "b": "Unpredicted"
  }
]
```